# AngularJS disable default form submit hook

Tags: angularjs

I have already existing forms on admin panel and i've wrapped it to `<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="app-nav">` and after that all forms stopped to work...
How can i disable default AngularJS behaviour to make all forms get back to work again?

https://jsfiddle.net/24sufpvn/
Here AngularJS prevents default form submission.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't find any solution except editing angular.js:
Need to replace line:

```
if (!('action' in attr)) {
```

to this:

```
if (false) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular.js prevent the native `<form>` submission because it's missing a valid `action` attribute.

I have edited your fiddle and added the missing `action` attribute, and now the form submits correctly:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
  <form method="post" action="https://formsubmit.co/your@email.com">
    <input type="submit" name="s" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/SlumDog1/kg6m5r7v/11/

Comment: It's a wordpress admin panel and i can't add action attibute to all forms...

Comment: Why not? You already wrapped them in an `ng-app` container. How about adding just an empty `action` attr? perhaps Angular.js will see that as valid in this condition: `if (!('action' in attr))`?

Comment: There're a lot of forms in wordpress admin and it will take a lot of time to find all of them and add action tag to them might break their functionality and as a result after wordpress update it will remove all of your changes...

Comment: Ok, but same goes for you your hardcoded change in Angular.js source code: if someone ever updates angular.js or reinstalls it, the code you changed will get overwritten and your project will break. The next developer in this project will NEVER understand what you did.. hence it's extremely not recommended to go this way.

Comment: Do you have another solution?

Comment: Yes, do it the right (ang longer) way. There's no way around it. Dirty solutions always come around at you. Change the forms instead of changing an already-written framework. The Wordpress forms are probably just static HTML files - why would it ever change? You do control the files in the project, don't you..?

Comment: Static???)) It's wordpress core forms, like user deleting, user editing. post filters, deleting posts, a lot of settings pages, post/pages/comments edit screens, there're hundreds of forms....

Comment: Oh man.. Now I understand what you're doing - making hardcoded changes in the core of 2 closed frameworks. Sounds like a bad idea. Good luck with that and your project.

Comment: Why in two? only in angularjs.

Comment: You also wrapped the whole WordPress framework with Angular.js, and the problem with the HTML forms can be only the tip of the iceberg. Both Angular and WP are now trying to control the DOM and dictate the whole user flow. Expect robust (and mysterious) bugs..

Comment: Angular controll only elements with angular attributes "ng-*" so there will be no any issues

Comment: That's inaccurate. You've just seen proof when all the forms in your project stopped working, and you had to change the source code of Angular.js itself to solve it, no less. There can be many additional problems down the road. Anyway, friend, I was just trying to help. Take it or leave it. Cheers